# What is the best way to organize a join within a foreach?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables: `{users, orders}`. In this example, let's say that for each 1 User in the `users` table, there are 100000 Orders in the `orders` table.

I have to use pyspark to generate a statement of Orders for each User. So, a single user will need his/her own list of Orders. Additionally, I need to send this statement to the real-world user via email (for example).

My first intuition was to apply a `DataFrame.foreach()` on the `users` DataFrame. This way, I can rely on the spark workers to handle the email sending individually. However, I now do not know the best way to get each User's Orders.

I will soon try the following (pseudo-code):

```
users_df = <my entire users DataFrame>
orders_df = <my entire orders DataFrame>

#this is poorly named for max understandability in this context
def foreach_function(row):
  user_id = row.user_id
  user_orders_df = orders_df.select(f'user_id = {user_id}')

  #here, I'd get any User info from 'row'
  #then, I'd convert all 'user_orders' to JSON
  #then, I'd prepare the email and send it

users_df.foreach(foreach_function)
```

It is my understanding that if I do my user-specific work in the `foreach` function, I will capitalize on Spark's scalability when doing that work. However, I am worried of two things:

- If I take all Orders up front...

  - Will that work?
  - Will I be taking too much? Will I be taking Orders on partitions who won't handle them (different User).
- If I create the `orders_df` (filtered) within the foreach function...

  - Will it work?
  - Will that be too much IO to DB?

The question ultimately is: How can I achieve this goal efficiently?

I have not yet tried anything here. I am doing so as we speak, but am suffering from choice-paralysis.

Please and thank you.

Comment: 1. what size table users?
2. do we can use BROADCAST for this table?

Comment: We don't have real-world data yet, but we estimate it to be in the 100,000s.